# Convert from UTC to local timezone give wrong result

Tags: swift, date, timezone, nsdate, utc

**Background**
I need to convert time string with format: "HH:mm" from UTC to local timezone. For example if UTC time is 09:00, local time (Stockholm/Europe) should be two hours ahead.

**Problem**
When I convert 09:00 (UTC) to Stockholm/Europe time I get 10:00. It should be 11:00.

```
func UTCToLocal(date:String) -> String {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")

    let dt = dateFormatter.date(from: date)
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current //Stockholm/Europe

    return dateFormatter.string(from: dt!)
}

print(UTCToLocal(date: "09:00")) //prints 10:00
```

Why is the timezone different from what it suppose to be?

Comment: Print `dt`. Update your question with its output. Most likely it is some old date that is causing your issue.

Comment: Unrelated but why set the `dateFormat` twice to the same format? And why use string interpolation on `date`? Just do `let dt = dateFormatter.date(from: date)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You specified only a time, but no day, therefore "09:00" is converted
to the date "2000-01-01 09:00:00 +0000". At that moment daylight saving time was not active in Stockholm, and the local time was 10:00.

If you want the conversion for the current day then you can set

```
dateFormatter.defaultDate = Date()
```