# UTC to PDT time conversion gives wrong time, it seems the times off by 1 hour

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, nsdateformatter, swift5

I am trying to convert time from UTC to PDT but it seems that the times off by 1 hour, I checked with IST but it returns the correct time.

**Code**

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE 'at' hh:mm a"
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "07:42 AM") {
   dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
   dateFormatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
   dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "PDT")
   print("Current Timezone: ", dateFormatter.timeZone ?? "")
   print("Converted time: ", dateFormatter.string(from: date))
}
else {
   print("Error........")
}
```

**Output:**

```
Current Timezone:  America/Los_Angeles (fixed)
Converted time:  11:42 PM
```

**Expected time:**

`Converted time:  12:42 am`

Comment: Is that the real code? I would expect that it prints "Error" because "07:42 AM" does not match the "EEEE 'at' hh:mm a" format.

Comment: yes, it's real code, but updated it after pasting here, 
it is dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a", 
thank you for letting me know

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [Convert from UTC to local timezone give wrong result](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46531583/1187415) to me.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, you are right. I wasn't able to find your answer before that's why I asked.